# In what order methods +initialize and +load called?

Tags: objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

Lets imagine that we have two classes:

```
@interface First : NSObject

@end

@interface Second : NSObject

@end

@implementation First
+(void)load
{
    NSLog(@"This must be called first");
}
@end

@implementation Second
+(void)load
{
    NSLog(@"And this must be called second");
}
@end
```

We have `+load` methods in each class. If we run this code, `This must be called first` will be first and `And this must be called second` will be second.

What determines the order in which the `+load` methods of this classes are called? In my experiment, if I move `@implementation` of second class before `@implementation` of first class - `And this must be called second` is printed first and `This must be called first` is printed second. Is this means that `+load` order depends only from order in source code?

In my real case I have precompiled framework with custom `+load` (some code are called before `main()` and I see logs from it), and I need to execute my code before this code (and as I understand - I can place it into `+load`, but I don't know how to change order). Or may be I can call my code before framework code with some other technique?

Answer (score 2):

You really can't rely on order, nor can you effectively control order.  By design.   `+load` should happen *before* the `+initialize` *of that class*, but they order of the two is seemingly indeterminate across multiple classes (which I find slightly surprising, but well within the rules).

This is a big part of why you shouldn't do any heavy lifting in `+load` or `+initialize`.   They really should only be used sparingly and only for initializing a small bit of highly localized state.   Touching other significant subsystems is dangerous because you'll be changing initialization order and behavior in ways that might break the system.  Shouldn't, but it might, it can, and it has in the past.

Instead, you really should try to have a "start here" point in your framework code that the client explicitly calls into.

Comment: Might be worth also pointing out that there's also a guarantee that a base class's +load and +initialize are called before its subclasses'.

Answer (score 2):

`+load` methods are invoked by the objc runtime as part of the image loading process (you can see this by breaking in your `load` method and printing a stacktrace).

The order in which `+load` methods are invoked seems to depend on the order of the objc class lists generated by clang.

If you look at the source code of the objc runtime, you'll see that [`load_images`](https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime/blob/master/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm#L2166) (the function called by dyld), calls [`prepare_load_methods`](https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime/blob/master/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm#L2866) to get a list of all objc classes in an image. `prepare_load_methods` calls [`_getObjc2NonlazyClassList`](https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime/blob/master/runtime/objc-file.mm#L63), which fetches the objc classlist from the `__objc_nlclslist` section in the image.

`load_images` then calls [`call_load_methods`](https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime/blob/master/runtime/objc-loadmethod.mm#L307), which goes through all loaded classes and invokes their `+load` methods.

Comment: Yes;  the order is an implementation detail subject to change.   Even if you were to back into the current order, that may not be stable over releases.   As well, any dynamic loading that comes into play will have additional loading phases.